# Typescript: How to derive from an interface that has optional fields?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
    interface IEmployee {
      settings: {
        external_payment: {
          connected_account?: {
            status: string;
            last4?: string;
            account_type_code?: string;
            bank_account_name?: string;
            verification_method?: string;
            institution: { name: string; institution_id?: string };
          };
        }
      }
      ...
    }
```

which I use to derive the type of my Employee

```
export interface Employee {
  settings: {
    external_payment: {
      connected_account?: {
        status: IEmployee['settings']['external_payment']['connected_account']['status'];
      };
    },
  },
}
```

However, because `connected_account` is optional, Typescript shows an error:

[image]

```
[tsserver 2339] [E] Property 'status' does not exist on type '{ status:
string; last4?: string | undefined; account_type_code?: string | undefined;
bank_account_name?: string | undefined; verification_method?: string |
undefined; institution: { ...; }; } | undefined'.
```

How would I correctly type the `status` field and base it off `external_payment.connected_account.status`?

Comment: `IEmployee` doesn't have a `settings` property in your example.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: You can use the `NonNullable<T>` utility type to strip `undefined` from the object type before indexing into it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5PE5w). Please see the answer to the linked question for more information.

Comment: @jcalz NonNullable worked great. Doesn't look the prettiest but it worked